# High need .NET7 SignalR not sending updates from WEB API

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr, cross-domain

I have a solution containing below projects:

1. Web API
2. Service Layer ( Containing SignalR )
3. Domain Layer
4. MVC Project

*Web API and MVC projects are running on different ports

SignalR is called in both API & MVC projects and works fine when calls coming from MVC ( UI Updated). however despite I have implemented whatever I did in startup file of MVC project in API and also activated CORS but any messages sent from API not gets reflected in MVC.

Need your help please (possibly by a sample source code to understand the case better).

Answer (score 0):

There are four projects under your solution where the `service layer` (which contains SignalR) is used as a similar public package to reduce the need to write repetitive code and to refer to it directly when needed. It's very good, and it's doable.

But what we need to be clear about is that in Signalr, there is the concept of [`SignalR client`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/client-features?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and `SignalR server`.

---

**ASP.NET CORE SignalR Server**

The project which contains the Hub class and will register the signalr middleware, and will use `app.MapHub<MainHub>("/mainhub");`. This project is the signalr server.

---

In your scenario, make sure that only MVC projects reference the `service layer` (including SignalR). Then used the `app.MapHub` method for registration and use.

You API project don't need to add `service layer` reference， it should be as
a signalr client [by using .net sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio). Then it can send the message to the hub.